# Pass a custom _form text field parameter to a second page Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, parameter-passing

I need to pass parameters from a form with values not in the database (so the form will have parameters only to be used by that page and never again). Upon the submitting of the form, I want to pass these parameters to a ruby script that is adapted into an html.erb page.

So far, all I can manage to do is pass one parameter (received from an earlier page of an object that did have both a model and a controller), but I cannot have the form pass my current form's parameters. The form below will display the ISBN obtained from the previous link_to correctly

This is currently my form:

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "pages", :action => "post_form", :condition =>     params[:condition], :isbn => params[:isbn], :price => params[:price], :description => params[:description], :comment => params[:comment]) do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag "Book ISBN" %><br />
    <%= params[:isbn] %>
  </div>

  <div class = "field">
    <%= label_tag "Condition" %>
    <%= select_tag :condition, raw("<option>Brand New'</option><option>Like   New</option><option>Very Good</option><option>Good</option><option>Acceptable</option>")%>
  </div>

  <div class = "field">
    <%= label_tag "Price" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :price %>
  </div>

  <div class = "field">
    <%= label_tag "Description" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :description %>
  </div>

  <div class = "field">
    <%= label_tag :comment %>
    <%= text_field_tag :comment %>
  </div>

  <div class = "actions">
    <%= submit_tag "Submit"%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I've checked my tail -f log/production.log and this is how I know that the ISBN is passed properly to the next page upon submission. Can anyone help me with figuring out how to pass the other parameters that have to be taken from the form itself?

====================================EDIT1=========================================
this is my code for post_form. It mostly just deals with the API from Half.com. We had initially tested this with success as a ruby script run through the command prompt

```
<%
require 'httpclient'
require 'nokogiri'
%>

<% isbn = params[:isbn] %>
<% condition = params[:condition] %>
<% price = params[:price] %>
<% description = params[:description] %>
<% comment = params[:comment] %>

<%
token = 'ourUniqueSellerToken'

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'utf-8') { |xml|
xml.AddItem('xmlns' => 'default', 'xmlns' => 'urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents') do
  xml.RequesterCredentials do
     xml.eBayAuthToken token
  end
  xml.Item do
    xml.AttributeArray do
      xml.Attribute('attributeLabel' => 'Condition') do
        xml.Value do
          xml.ValueLiteral condition
        end
      end
      xml.Attribute('attributeLabel' => 'Notes') do
        xml.Value do
          xml.ValueLiteral comment
        end
      end
    end
    xml.Country 'US'
    xml.Currency 'USD'
    xml.Description description
    xml.ListingDuration 'GTC'
    xml.ListingType 'Half'
    xml.Location 'CO'
    xml.Quantity '1'
    xml.StartPrice price
    xml.ExternalProductID do
      xml.Value isbn
      xml.type 'ISBN'
    end
  end
end
}

client = HTTPClient.new
uri = 'https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll'

headers = {
        'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL' => '823',
        'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME' => 'ourDevName',
        'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME' => 'ourAppName',
        'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME' => 'ourCertName',
        'X-EBAY-API-SITEID' => '0',
        'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME' => 'AddItem'
}

results = client.post_content(uri, builder.to_xml, headers)

doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(results)
%>

<b><%= "Returned: "+doc.css("Ack").text %> </b>
<b><%= "Listing ID: "+doc.css("ItemID").text %></b>
```

The controller for the form is just a blank function:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def search
  end

  def listing
  end

  def post_form
  end

end
```

============The following is from my development log (opening the form page)==============

```
Started GET "/pages/listing?class=btn+btn-mini&isbn=9780307588364" for 138.67.201.236 at 2013-06-04 20:33:01 +0000
Processing by PagesController#listing as HTML
  Parameters: {"class"=>"btn btn-mini", "isbn"=>"9780307588364"}
  Rendered pages/_form.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered pages/listing.html.erb within layouts/application (1.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 3.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started POST "/pages/post_form" for 138.67.201.236 at 2013-06-04 20:33:09 +0000
```

(upon submittal)

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/pages/post_form"):
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:143:in `pass'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:155:in `invalidate'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:71:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  passenger (4.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:77:in     `process_request'
  passenger (4.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:135:in     `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (4.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:106:in     `main_loop'
  passenger (4.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:449:in `block (4 levels)    in start_threads'
  passenger (4.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/utils/robust_interruption.rb:108:in   `disable_interruptions'
  passenger (4.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:444:in `block (3 levels)    in start_threads'
```

(Upon refresh)

```
Started GET "/pages/post_form" for 138.67.201.236 at 2013-06-04 20:33:14 +0000
Processing by PagesController#post_form as HTML
  Rendered pages/post_form.html.erb within layouts/application (252.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 257ms (Views: 256.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: what does the 'post_form' action in your pages controller look like in your code?

Comment: edited my question with the pages controller and post_form if you need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the parameters twice: one time by url parameters in the form's action, that is rendered to something like

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/pages?comment=params%5B%3Acomment%5D&amp;condition=cond&amp;description=params%5B%3Adescription%5D&amp;isbn=isbn&amp;price=params%5B%3Aprice%5D" method="post">
```

and a second time as `POST` parameters in the form (except the ISBN).

Drop the parameters in the form and set them as default value in the text fields:

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "pages", :action => "post_form" %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :isbn, params[:isbn] %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :condition, params[:condition] %>

...

<div class = "field">
  <%= label_tag "Description" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :description, param[:description] %>
</div>
```

And it's good practice to have the heavy work done by a model. You can use an `ActiveModel`, if it's not related to the DB.
Then you can also use this model for the form and use normal form helpers.

Addendum

Your logs show, that you are missing a route for the `POST` to `pages#post_form`.
Add in your routes.rb

```
post 'pages/post_form'
```

Submitting the form is done by a `POST` request, which fails.
"Refresh" is done by a `GET` request.

In Rails you should have different actions for `GET` and `POST`. They really do something completely different.

Comment: Thank you with the response, but I'm still having trouble. I've done as you've suggested, only passing the parameters once, but I don't think they're actually being sent to the next page. How would I be able to check this? I'm looking in the log for some indicator of a passed parameter, and am finding none. Thanks for your help

Comment: First look at the final HTML page to be shure it's a valid form. Then you may use `firebug`'s network tab to see, what is actually sent by the browser. This schould end up in the params hash, that is logged in the `development.log`. Use the development environment for developing. It's much more verbose.

Comment: That was actually something I was curious about. See, when I first submit the form, the next page will initially say that the page cannot be found, but if you then refresh the page, post_form is visible, but the listing says that it has failed.
Could the reload requirement be what is causing my issue?

Comment: posted after my files above

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help! You've helped me greatly with this. I can see the parameters being passed now. Thank you!!