# Bring value from one webpage to another webpage in Ruby on Rails website without database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Summary**

I'm trying to bring a value from one webpage to another webpage on my Ruby on Rails site without saving it a second time into my MySQL database. I'm new to Ruby, so thanks in advance for your patience.

**Overview**

My website users can save a map they have created. Now, I want them to be able to edit the maps.

I have a webpage, newmaps.html.erb, that renders the map. The map has a unique ID:

```
    <%= newsavedmap.id %>
```

There's an "Edit" button under the map. When the user clicks "edit", I want him to be taken to another webpage, maptry.html.erb , which is essentially a form that lets the user edit the map.

**Problem**

I want that specific newsavedmap.id to transfer over to maptry.html.erb so that I can load the form with newsavedmap.startingaddress, newsavedmap.endingaddress, and all of the other data associated with that record.

I think I'm supposed to use "POST", but I'm not sure how to do that in this situation. This link has given me some ideas, but my form is not a Rails form so I'm not sure how to translate it into my own solution: [Pass a custom _form text field parameter to a second page Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925358/pass-a-custom-form-text-field-parameter-to-a-second-page-rails)

**maptry.html.erb**

```
    <div id="control_panel">
    <div>
    <input id="startingaddress" type="text" name="starthere" size="56"></p>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input id="endingaddress" type="text" name="endhere" size="56"></p>
    </div>
    <div>    
        <input onclick="calcRoute();" id="showmapview" value="Show Map">
    </div>   
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you read any books or tutorials on how to create views in Rails? What your asking is a fundamental part of how the controllers and views interact in the MVC model.

Comment: Hi, mbratch. `maptry.html.erb` and `newmaps.html.erb` are both within my `/views/itineraries` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after a night of research, I was able to pull together a few different sources that helped me get an answer to this one. The most helpful answers were here: [pass parameter by link_to ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898737/pass-parameter-by-link-to-ruby-on-rails) and [Pass Variable between Views in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931942/pass-variable-between-views-in-rails)

I learned how to use link_to to pass the parameters from one view to another view (one webpage to another, to a user). Here is how I did it:

**newmaps.html.erb**

```
    <%= link_to 'Edit', maptry_path(:newsavedmap_id => newsavedmap.id) %>
```

The above code uses the anchor text "Edit" and links the user to the maptry.html.erb view. It also brings over the newsavedmap_id. Then, I updated the maptry_controller

**maptry_controller.rb**

```
    @newsavedmap = Newsavedmap.find(params[:newsavedmap_id])
```

With this in place, I can add any of the information from the map that I want just by inserting @newsavedmap.WHATEVER. See below. I also added the params[:newsavedmap_id] in a hidden field just in case this was necessary.

**maptry.html.erb**

```
    <input name="newsavedmapid" type="hidden" value="<%= params[:newsavedmap_id] %>" />  
    <input id="start" type="text" name="starthere" size="56" value="<%= @newsavedmap.start%>"></p>
```

Likely, this isn't the best or only solution out there, but like I said, I'm very new to Rails. I appreciate any other answers people have so I can continue to learn. Thanks!